# asp.net (c#) menu/menuItem event/event-handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, menu, menuitem

Is it possible to use asp.net standard Menu (server-control) for tasks other than navigation?

For example: I want to use asp.net menu to add a button control to the asp.net panel (server-control).

This idea of mine is basically came from the winforms environment, where there are events and event-handlers for menu and menu-items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do anythings during MenuItemClick event handler.

Comment: I am having trouble in finding click event of asp menu item
i have tried:

    protected void NavigationMenu_MenuItemClick(Object sender,
      System.Web.UI.WebControls.MenuEventArgs e)
{
 if (e.Item.Text == "Home")
//Code here
}
but does;t  hit the breakpoint while debugging & menu click
how can I access the click Event of the asp:menuItem Click

Comment: Did you set the `OnMenuItemClick` attribute of menu control? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menuitemclick.aspx

Comment: Thanks, yes that was the error & Thanks after figured it out earlier.